# textarea excess space with php

Tags: textarea, whitespace

I have a simple text area box with php in the box on refresh:

```
<textarea><?php    //php in here    ?></textarea>
```

At the moment, the php is very long and when it does echo out the value the box should be there is a lot of white space in between.  i think this is because of the large amount of php (not shown).  is there a way to use the trim() or a css attribute that aligns the text to the left?

Answer (score 1):

Anything between two PHP is extracted by the compiler and the result of the PHP is inserted at that point. No new lines or anything within the tags is outputted. You are also allowed to use new lines within the tags.
Example:

```
<textarea>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    echo("hello");
}
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: so what could be the reason why the text isnt alight to the left and is several spaces over?

Comment: That would probably be caused by padding or something. Post your real html (without the internal PHP, leave the tags) so I can examine it.

Comment: <textarea id ='textbox' autocomplete='off'  
     readonly='readonly'>     
     
     Login to answer...     </textarea>

Comment: Well.. thats not really much to go on since you just ended it with dots. But you do have a space before Login which will show up. As a note, any html including any whitespace characters will be show up as raw text within the textarea.